# service worker register is not registering

Tags: service-worker

I am trying to register service worker in my application. but its not being register.

**Code**
https://github.com/faisalmjanjua/PWATesting.git

**app.js**

```
console.log("testing app.js")

if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    console.log("testing service worker")
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(){
        console.log("register service worker")
    });
}
```

**console**

[image]

I dont know where I am making mistake. I check the multiple site how to register the service worker and its same as I am coding. Even my browser is service worker enable.

Any help? why `testing service worker` is not showing in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Service workers are restricted to running across HTTPS for security reasons.**

---

you need to serve your code on Https to use them (it looks like you are on HTTP)

---

*Workaround*:

you can add an exception for your host in Chrome-Flags to treat it as a secure origin

[image: chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure]

this is the page you can set your origins

> chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

Comment: Yep, only localhost is considered secure, if you're server is on a different machine/IP address, the page needs to be served over HTTPS